# "http:" in href attribute without forward slashes

Tags: html

What is the affect of using `http:` without forward slashes after the colon.

This is what I know/tested so far:

- `..` = the domain (http://example.com)
- `->` = after the href link is clicked

---

**Case A** - `<a href="http:#">..`

```
From a file at root directory: ../ -> ../#

From a file at a subdirectory: ../sub/ -> ../sub/#

From a get or rewrited URL: ../?q=about OR ../about/ -> ../#
```

---

**Case B** - `<a href="http:something">..`

```
From a file at root directory: ../ -> ../something

From a file at a subdirectory: ../sub/ -> ../sub/something

From a get or rewrited URL: ../?q=about OR ../about/ -> ../something
```

---

So what's happenin?

Comment: That doesn't look valid. Where have you seen it in use?

Comment: @isherwood No it is not valid, but I was able to use it and somehow it did work but just a little more different than other href attribute values. I used it at a path field in drupal to get arround their url validition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) explains how URIs are interpreted. The general syntax is:

```
URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]

      hier-part   = "//" authority path-abempty
                  / path-absolute
                  / path-rootless
                  / path-empty
```

If you leave out the `//` after the scheme name, the `hier-part` part of the URI is interpreted as either an absolute path or rootless path, depending on whether it begins with `/`, or an empty path if it's empty.

When there's no server name after `http:`, it uses the same server as the page containing the URI.

If the path is empty, it uses the path of the current page.

If the path is relative, it's interpreted relative to the directory of the path of the current page.

If the path is absolute, it's used as given.

Details of the above resolution algorithm are in Section 5 of the RFC.

Comment: It's a valid URI but it's not a valid HTTP URL. There is another standard for URL: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1738#section-5

HTTP URL must comply with the regexp: 
httpurl        = "http://" hostport [ "/" hpath [ "?" search ]]

Comment: @lagivan If that were true, you couldn't have `href="file.html"` because it's missing the scheme prefix. The two RFCs have to be read together -- the syntax in 1738 is after resolving relative URIs.

Comment: Good point, you're right. I've just noticed it's mentioned in the header of RFC 3986 that it updates RFC 1738.

Answer (score 0):

No way is this valid. You have to use "//" after the http: to tell the browser that the link is a web page.If you use../ and not http you ere telling the browser to look for a folder behind the folder he is in.Also if you use href="google.com" your browser won't look for Google.com(site) but for a file with name Google.com in the same directory.

Comment: :D No no, you didn't understand my explanation correctly. Check my legend. `..` = `http://example.com` so `../` = `http://example.com/`

Comment: Sorry for misunderstoonding